# unable to make .apk using ionic codova

Tags: android, angular, ionic-framework

I am very new in ionic framework.I want a side menu using ionic 3 framework.I make already that app.It run in ionic lab but when I build for android as apk an error comes.

> typescript error 
>               Type QrPage in /Users/arpan/Desktop/rad/src/pages/qr/qr.ts is part of the declarations of 2 modules: 
>               AppModule in /Users/arpan/Desktop/rad/src/app/app.module.ts and QrPageModule in 
>               /Users/arpan/Desktop/rad/src/pages/qr/qr.module.ts! Please consider moving QrPage in 
>               /Users/arpan/Desktop/rad/src/pages/qr/qr.ts to a higher module that imports AppModule in 
>               /Users/arpan/Desktop/rad/src/app/app.module.ts and QrPageModule in 
>               /Users/arpan/Desktop/rad/src/pages/qr/qr.module.ts. You can also create a new NgModule that exports and 
>               includes QrPage in /Users/arpan/Desktop/rad/src/pages/qr/qr.ts then import that NgModule in AppModule in 
>               /Users/arpan/Desktop/rad/src/app/app.module.ts and QrPageModule in 
>               /Users/arpan/Desktop/rad/src/pages/qr/qr.module.ts.

this the error

> app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { ErrorHandler, NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicApp, IonicErrorHandler, IonicModule } from 'ionic-angular';

import { MyApp } from './app.component';
import { HomePage } from '../pages/home/home';
import { ListPage } from '../pages/list/list';
import { QrPage } from '../pages/qr/qr';
import { NgxQRCodeModule } from 'ngx-qrcode2';
import { BarcodeScanner } from '@ionic-native/barcode-scanner';

import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen';

@NgModule({
declarations: [
MyApp,
HomePage,
ListPage,
QrPage
],
imports: [
BrowserModule,
IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp),
NgxQRCodeModule

],
bootstrap: [IonicApp],
entryComponents: [
MyApp,
HomePage,
ListPage,
QrPage
],
providers: [
StatusBar,
SplashScreen,
{provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler},
BarcodeScanner
]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

> qr.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPageModule } from 'ionic-angular';
import { QrPage } from './qr';

@NgModule({
declarations: [
QrPage,
],
imports: [
IonicPageModule.forChild(QrPage),
],
exports: [
QrPage,
]
})
export class QrPageModule {}
```

This is a side menu ionic app.and i add a page their have a qr code generator.i use ngx-qrcode2.
please help me how i do that?

Answer (score 0):

this is an common error caused by the Lazy Load feature of ionic.
You need to import the QrPageModule in the App.Module IMPORTS and remove the QrPage in declarations and entryComponents.
Try that and see if it works!